# Break ties in ranking without jump in R

Tags: r

I have a simple Matrix and want to have the ranks for each entry.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  5    8
[2,]  8    5
```

When I use rank() with ties.method=min it has a jump after the tie:

```
rankMatrix[] <- rank(-Matrix, ties.method="min")
```

it gives me the following:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  3    1
[2,]  1    3
```

My problem is that I do not want to have a jump in rank after the tie, i.e.:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2    1
[2,]  1    2
```

Is there any way to achieve this sort of ranking?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We could do with `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
m1[] <- dense_rank(-m1)
m1
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
#[2,]    1    2
```